# In this program we didnot wrote getter and constructor in AccountService class . Then how jdbcTemplate is beeing injected in this class?

Tags: java, spring

```
    package sinha.priyank.txn;

    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcDaoSupport;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
    // How we are injecting JdbcTemplet in this class as we dont have    //any getter/setter and constructor
    @Transactional
    public class AccountService extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport {

        @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,timeout=10)
        public void deposit(int accountNumber , double amount)
            {
                getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update("update accounts set balance=balance+? where account_number=?", amount,accountNumber);
                getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update("insert into statements (account_number,transaction_amount,transaction_type,id) values(?,?,?,?)", accountNumber , amount , "Deposit",121);
            }

        @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW , timeout=40)
        public void withdraw(int accountNumber , double amount)
            {
                getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update("update accounts set balance=balance+? where account_number=?", amount,accountNumber);
                getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update("insert into statements (account_number,transaction_amount,transaction_type,id) values(?,?,?,?)", accountNumber , amount , "Withdraw",180);
            }
    }
```

/* 
    *
    //   SPring.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>


   <bean id="dataSourceBean" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"/>
        <property name="password" value="khanjan"/>
        <property name="username" value="system"/>
    </bean>


   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"/>
   </bean>



    <bean id="jdbcTemplateBean" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"/>
    </bean>


     <bean id="accountServiceBean" class="sinha.priyank.txn.AccountService">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplateBean"/>
    </bean>




</beans>
```

*
*/

/*********
// Main Program

package sinha.priyank.txn;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TxnClient {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


     ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    // This is a class contain void main
    AccountService accountservices = context.getBean("accountServiceBean" , AccountService.class);
    System.out.println("***** Calling Deposit ****");
    accountservices.deposit(1001, 500);
    System.out.println("***** Calling Withdraw *****");
    accountservices.withdraw(1001, 300);
    System.out.println("ACCOUNT OPERATION COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY");
}
```

}

*****/

Comment: What is `SimpleJdbcDaoSupport`?

Answer (score 0):

A getter and a setter for the template are declared in the superclass `JdbcDaoSupport` which `SimpleJdbcDaoSupport` extends.